# c++ Variable being overwritten during each loop iteration

Tags: c++, variables

I am developing simulation software that requires some predetermined behaviour of an entity for certain aspects of its functionality. The behaviour that I am currently working on is setting an entity in a simulation environment to move in a 'spiral' about a point determined by the user.

There are several existing choices of behaviour that the user can set for the entity by selecting particular options from the GUI. The way I intend to implement this new behaviour is as follows:

- Get the angle from entity's current location to the spiral origin (the point specified by the user that the entity will spiral around).
- Check the entity's current distance from the spiral origin:
- If it's greater than a certain distance from the origin, move directly towards the origin until the it is a certain distance from the origin, then start spiralling.
- If it's less than a certain distance from the origin, move away from the origin, until it is that distance from it, then start spiralling.
- Every time the entity completes a circuit of the spiral, the value displayed in the GUI that shows the number of circuits completed should be updated.

I have started writing a loop to implement this behaviour, and I intend to increment the number of circuits completed, by checking the angle of the entity from the origin with every iteration of the loop- every time that angle is the same as it was when the spiral behaviour was engaged, I will know that another circuit has been completed. But, since I am getting the angle between the entity and the origin at the start of the loop, this value will be updated with every iteration of the loop- which will mean that the entity will never again reach that angle from the origin, because the angle will keep changing.

What I would like to know is if there is a way of setting the value of a variable during the first iteration of a loop, and then not changing that value again in any other iteration of the loop? Could I assign that value to a global variable, and make it an 'absolute' value, so that even if I tried to change its value again, I wouldn't be able to?

**EDIT**

The obvious suggestion would be to set that angle variable value outside the loop, but I can't do this due to the nature of the existing behaviours that have been implemented, and what happens when the user selects one of the behaviours.

Comment: You should use a detector variable which you should set to true (or even 0 to 1) to detect if your desired variable is now initialised and shouldn't be overridden. Also, what have coded to achieve this i.e. where is your source code that has this issue? Could you please post it out?

Comment: It's unclear to me why tyou can't do the obvious suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by detector variable? Do you mean have another `if` statement to check whether the 'angle' variable should be updated with each iteration? The function is quite large- because it is being used to implement what happens when any one of several behaviour options are chosen, but I will paste the `if` statement for this behaviour.

Comment: Actually- that sounds like a really good suggestion- Cheers! Something like `if(angle == null){set its value} else {don't};`?

Comment: You can do this every iteration, and it's easy to wrap the value in a set-once wrapper if you want to automate it, but it's a bit ugly. Can't you just have a _get-in-position_ loop (which fixes up the distance), then record the current angle, and then run your actual spiral-counting loop?

Comment: I can't do the obvious suggestion because the behaviour is itself being set inside the loop.

Comment: The problem with that is that I have a `steerStep` function which is telling the entity to move in a particular direction/ with a particular behaviour at every iteration- it's this `steerStep` function that sets the entity to spiral (or to move directly from A to B, or in any one of a number of other defined ways).

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like a state machine (where _get-in-position_ and _spiral_n_times_ are different states, and the latter saves the current angle when you enter that state)

Comment: You might need to rethink how you detect the completion of a circuit.  What is the resolution/precision of the angle variable? My hunch is that a floating point value (high precision) will unlikely match the initial angle after many iterations of your loop/steerStep function.  Depending on the number of iterations of the simulation that it takes to complete a circuit around the origin you might need a different test rather than exact equality of the angle to determine that a full circuit around the origin has completed.

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like you should do the first iteration of the loop *outside the loop* to set up this one-time variable, and then do `n-1` iterations inside the loop. If the loop body is complicated, put it in a function. Also keep in mind that if you happen to use floating point values for your angle the chances that they're ever equal after the first iteration are slim to none.

```
int loop_body(params)
{
    // Do stuff.
    return first_iteration_value;
}

int initial_value = loop_body(params);
for(init; condition; incr)
{
    loop_body(params);
}
```